# Calling shared examples with dynamic computed parameters

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

I am a newbie to capybara, rspec integration testing.
How to call a shared example with dynamically computed parameter?

```
shared_examples_for "a measurable object" do |example, display_name|
    it "is example - #{display_name}" do
      visit "www.example.com?args=test"
      expect(page.find("#examplediv").text).to eq example 
    end
end

describe "example" do
  # where to compute this dynamic_value
  it_behaves_like "a measurable object", dynamic_value, "example 1"
end
```

Both describe and shared_example are in separate files.

In the code snippet above I want to compute dynamic_value based on the data obtained from a method call.

Where do I compute the value of "dynamic_value"?

I have tried computing in `before :each` and `before :all` both of which did not work.

It would also be nice if you explain me the call cycle with describe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well this should help you atleast with the "call cycle" http://www.wulftone.com/2012/01/22/rspec-gotchas-before-after-all-and-each/ . Other than that your question is a bit unclear to me

Comment: That blog does not talk about shared examples and when the it_behaves_like are preprocessed to create unique "it" blocks based on the arguments.

Comment: You asked abouit the call cycle of a describe block and mentioned attempting to use `before :each` and `before :all` thus my comment. Otherwise you question is unclear as to what your desire is because the only value that will pass based on the question asked is the string "dynamic value" (`expect(example).to eq "dynamic value"`)

Comment: sorry that my question caused confusion. I tried to describe my problem using a pseudo code. I have updated my code. I am not understanding where to compute dynamic_value variable for it_behaves_like. I appreciate your help. `before :each` and `before :all` did not help me.

Comment: Okay it's the `it_behaves_like` that is your concern. Are you saying you want to randomly test different shared groups because the syntax for `it_behaves_like` would be `it_behaves_like "a measurable object", value, "example 1"` but a dynamic value seems odd here when you are testing specifically what is on a page.  https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group

Comment: Sorry again, I want to test single shared example with different arguments. (updated code) But the arguments are based on data that is fetched by a service call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I am still not 100% sure I understand you intentions but I think I have enough to offer a basic explanation now. I would implement this concept as such:

```
shared_examples_for "a page parser" do |dom_object,value|
  it "the text in #{dom_object} should equal #{value} on #{url}" do
    visit url
    expect(page.find("##{dom_object}").text).to eq value
  end
end

describe "example" do
  let(:url) { "www.example.com?args=test" }    
  values_obtained_from_service_call = Service.call(url)
  # We will assume this is something like [{dom_object: examplediv, value: "Hello World!"}]
  values_obtained_from_service_call.each do |test| 
    it_should_behave_like "a page parser", test[:dom_object], test[:value]
  end
end
```

This will iterate through the `values_obtained_from_service_call` and test them all using the shared example.

As I said I am still not sure why you want to do this but functionally it should work.