# How to pass variables with the same name in rspec's shared_examples?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Let's imagine I have some tests and want to use shared examples, e.g.:

```
RSpec.shared_examples "shared examples" do
  let(:x) { "" }
  
  it "should be equal to 5" do
    expect(x).to eq(5)
  end
end
```

and then use it like:

```
  describe "my tests" do
    let(:x) { 5 }

    it_behaves_like "shared examples" do
      let(:x) { x }
    end
  end
```

I know that I can do that implicitly, without passing `let(:x) { x }` to the child block and everything will work. But what I'm trying to achieve - is to add more clarity to my tests.

So the question is: how to pass a variable (override if you want) with the same name without falling into maximum call stack error to a child shared examples block?

Please let me know if my approach is not right in general.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the question but shared examples can take arguments. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980787/calling-shared-examples-with-dynamic-computed-parameters or more robustly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957628/rails-rspec-testing-crud-actions-with-shared-examples

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define the variable inside blocks, `let` is lazy-evaluated, so it is not evaluated until the first time
the method it defines is invoked, but they need to be inside blocks like `context`,  something like this:

```rb
RSpec.describes "shared examples" do  

  context 'when x has value' do
    let(:x) { 5 }

    it "should be equal to 5" do
      expect(x).to eq(5)
    end
  end

  context 'when x is empty' do
    let(:x) { '' }

    it "should be empty" do
      expect(x).to eq('')
    end
  end
end
```